# Windows 10 N: problems with programs what expect the full Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player

I had windows 7 N x64 and when I upgraded to windows 10, it upgraded to Windows 10 N x64...Something I deeply regret because lots of programs expect user to have the full Windows with the Windows Media Player (or it's DLLs) to run.

No worries I thought, I will install the Windows Media Feature Pack and all will be solved. But it's not that simple.

I installed both :

- Microsoft-Windows-MediaFeaturePack-OOB-Package_x64.msu

and

- KB3099229_x64.msu

both in 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

Still, some programs won't run complaining the WMP is not there or that WMVCore.dll is missing. Actually WMVCore.dll IS missing. Nowhere to be found on my system.

I downloaded WMVCore from the internet (yeah I know it's a bad thing...) but then, the programs complain about other DLLs. I didn't want to go down that road so my questions are very simple :

- How can I install all WMP DLLs to my system ?

or

- How can I upgarde my Windows 10 N to a regular Windows 10 without having to reinstall ?

Best regards
Denis

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is actually a newer feature pack : 
KB3133719 which can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356. Which solves those issues.

I really don't understand how Microsoft manages it's Media Feature Packs : you have 3 different packs, and the older packs pages never mention "This pack has been superseeded by KBxxxx" . Should be simple to do though ...